# Java8 sublists of a List<> using lambdas

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a problem which I feel would be perfect for streams and/or lambdas. On the other hand I don't want to overcomplicate this, but since will use this specific technique in many variations (run function on a sublist), I would like some ideas about how to get it right from the beginning.

I have a `List<Product> productList`.

I want to be able to iterate over all sublists in `productList`. For example all sublists with size=30. This sublist should then be used as an argument to a function.

This is my current, naive, solution:

```
List<Product> products=...
// This example uses sublists of size 30
for (int i = 0; i < products.size() - 29; i++) {
    // sublist start index is inclusive, but end index is exclusive
    List<Product> sublist = products.subList(i, i + 30);
    Double res = calc(sublist);
}

// an example of a function would be moving average
```

How would this be implemented using lambdas?

EDIT
I tried to come up with the simplest possible example to illustrate the problem. After some comments, I realized that a perfect example is calculating a moving average. First MAVG is calculated on sublist [0..29], second on [1..30], third on [2..31] and so on.

Comment: Using streams and lambdas won't make the code more readable, on the contrary.

Comment: What is the bigger problem you are trying to solve, why do you need sublists of 30? Also you are not making a sublist size 30 but a list that 29 products smaller then the full list.

Comment: this was just an example, and above code works (at least the original using same type of solution - this was a simplified example). See EDIT for more context.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov not really, using that example, I want sublists: ['a','b','c'],['b','c'.'d'],['c','d','e'],['d','e','f'] etc etc, like a "sliding window"

Answer (score 7):

Unless I'm missing something obvious...

```
IntStream.range(0, products.size() - 29)
            .mapToObj(i -> products.subList(i, i + 30))
            .map(list -> calc(list))
            .forEach... // or any other terminal op
```

Well if you want to run more then a single function to these sublists, like:

```
double result = calc(sublist)
log(sublist) // void
double res = diffCalc(sublist)
```

you are probably off staying with the usual for loop.

a `map` operation does a single action on a sublist, it could be made to do more in a stream, but that will look really ugly IMO.

Comment: I guess this is what I am looking for, however I can't say I understand it. Would you consider this 'state of the art' when calculating a moving average  as in my EDIT?

Comment: BTW... the arbitrary constants (29 & 30) was just what I used when the example used sublists of size 30.

Comment: @PeterAndersson It's fairly standard code for [iterating over indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams/8376/using-intstream-to-iterate-over-indexes#t=201704031927098665565).

Comment: @Eugene no, as you see in my EDIT, a moving average is a better example. Where index 0..29 => avg[0], index 1..30 => agv[1], index 2..31 => avg[2] and so on, A normal moving average.

Comment: ^ A moving average can be calculated _significantly_ more efficiently if you just scan the list one by one.

Comment: yes, but as I specified in the question, I want to run several (a lot) more complicated functions in the same kind of way.

Comment: @9000 moving average detail was added after the answer.

Comment: yes, ATM I dont see any benefit with changing my approach. I just "felt" that applying a lamdba function and some stream magic would make the code more clean but for now that deosnt seem to be the case.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind using third party libraries, there is a method `subLists` in [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) that does exactly what you want:

```
List<Product> products = ...
Stream<List<Product>> lists = StreamEx.ofSubLists(products, 30, 1);
```

Comment: This solution implements a fixed window of non-overlapping sublists, e.g. `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`.  The question is asking for a sliding window of overlapping sublists, e.g. `[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that code could be less clear with using lambdas. Maybe plain old **if** is better that modern **lambda**?

```java
    int sizeSubList = 30;

    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++)
        calc(products.subList(i, Math.min(i + sizeSubList, products.size())));
```

Comment: Yes I will probably stick with the old way. One problem with your code is however that some lists will be smaller than 30 items, which the hard-coded offsets in my examlpe takes care of. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature can be used to achieve the desired result:

```java
List<Double> results = productList.stream()
        .gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(30))
        .map(sublist -> calc(sublist))
        .toList();
```

This uses the new [`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)) method with the new built-in [`Gatherers.windowSliding`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowSliding(int)) gatherer to convert the map's entry set from `Stream<Entry>` to a pairwise `Stream<List<Entry>>`.  Each of these two-element lists is then transformed to a two-element `String[]` using the existing [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) method.

## Walkthrough

Stream walkthrough using sublist size 3, and a function that averages the values in the sublist:

```
[
  Product(value = 0),
  Product(value = 1),
  Product(value = 2),
  Product(value = 3),
  Product(value = 4)
]

->

[
  [Product(value = 0), Product(value = 1), Product(value = 2)],
  [Product(value = 1), Product(value = 2), Product(value = 3)],
  [Product(value = 2), Product(value = 3), Product(value = 4)]
]

->

[1, 2, 3]
```

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.

[`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherers.windowSliding`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowSliding(int))

> Returns a Gatherer that gathers elements into windows -- encounter-ordered groups of elements -- of a given size, where each subsequent window includes all elements of the previous window except for the least recent, and adds the next element in the stream. […]
>
> Example:
>
> ```java
> // will contain: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows2 =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(2)).toList();
>
> // will contain: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows6 =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(6)).toList();
> ```